# How to Extract custom Text from Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have text like

```
   "From: [your-name] <[your-email]>
    Subject: [your-subject]
    Message Body: [your-message]"
```

I want to extract the strings enclosed by `[ ]`.

Like:

```
your-name
your-email
your-subject
your-message
```

How I can do this using `preg_match_all()`?

Comment: I don't see any array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all matches from your input:

```
$text = 'From: [your-name] <[your-email]> Subject: [your-subject] Message Body: [your-message]';
preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Which will output:

```
{ [0]=> string(11) "[your-name]" [1]=> string(12) "[your-email]" [2]=> string(14) "[your-subject]" [3]=> string(14) "[your-message]" }
```

If you don't want the brackets included:

```
$text = 'From: [your-name] <[your-email]> Subject: [your-subject] Message Body: [your-message]';
preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Which will output:

```
{ [0]=> string(9) "your-name" [1]=> string(10) "your-email" [2]=> string(12) "your-subject" [3]=> string(12) "your-message" }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Amo

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = 'From: [your-name] <[your-email]> Subject: [your-subject] Message Body: [your-message]';

// the pattern is very simple in your case, because you want to get the 
// content that is enclosed inside square brackets []
// \s means any whitespace character, where \S means any non whitespace character
$pattern = '/\[[\s\S]+?\]/';

//the created $matches variable is an array containing all the matched data
preg_match_all($pattern,$text,$matches);


// print out the matches array 
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks @hamism

I solved it like :


     `preg_match('/\[.*?\]/', $formvalue[2], $matches);`